# sql: what is the difference between LIKE %...% and LIKE?

Tags: mysql, sql

what is the difference between below two sql sentences:

1.

```
SELECT pid, config, constants
FROM sys_template
WHERE config LIKE '%code = LIST%'
```

2.

```
SELECT pid, config, constants
FROM sys_template
WHERE config LIKE 'code = LIST'
```

Comment: -1 because it's just to read simple sql tutorial to get this answer

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is basic information that can be easily found in MySQL documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In your First query it shows all config column data which contains **code = LIST**
2. In your second query it shows all config column data which exact to **code = LIST**

LIKE supports wildcards.  Usually it uses the % or _ character for the wildcard.

For know more about [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

Answer (score 1):

`%` is a *wildcard character* to match any string. The latter matches only exactly `code = LIST` (basically working as `=` here), whereas the former matches `foocode = LISTbar` (for instance) as well.

To match a single arbitrary character, you can use `?` as a wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

"%" sign is used to define wildcards (missing letters) both before and after the pattern.It satisfied all these:

- 'acb code = LIST 12'
- 'efasd code = LIST sdf'
- 'whatever code = LIST whatever'

while query 2 only satisfies one string:

- code = LIST

[Sql Like details here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The operator `%` in LIKE condition mean whatever signs.

For your example 1 the result will contain only items that config is exact 'code = LIST' (the upper and lower case are not taken in mysql), in the second example the result will contain every config that as 'code = LIST' in it.

Answer (score 0):

First will find rows where `config` has inside  `code = LIST` for example:

```
code = LIST
aaacode = LISTaaaa
code = LISTaaaa
aaacode = LIST
```

Second will find only

```
code = LIST
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the `LIKE` operator, the `%` indicates that it should match any text occurring before or after that point.
For example, `'%code'` will return any of the following:

```
code
acode
abccode
abcdefcode
```

Whereas `'code%'` will return any of the following:

```
code
codea
codeabc
codeabcdef
```

Therefore, `'%code%'` will return any of the following:

```
code
acodea
abccodeabc
abcdefcodeabcdef
```

If you use `'code'` without the `%` then even though you are using `LIKE` you will actually run an exact search.